# How to open new chart to the adjacent <div> on bar click in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and need two charts(lets assume Chart a and chart B). So creating one is simple. On bar click of chart(Chart A) I want a new chart(Chart B) to open adjacent to the existing `<div>`(Chart A). So both chart should be visible once bar is clicked. New chart (chart B) should be different for each bar clicked of first Chart (Chart A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply bind click event on a bar, then create second chart in a specific div, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/147/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: renderSecond
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 100,
            name: 'test'
        }, {
            y: 34,
            name: 'click'
        }, {
            y: 67,
            name: 'other'
        }]
    }]
});

function renderSecond(e) {
    var point = this;
    $("#detail").highcharts({
        title: {
            text: point.name + ':' + point.y
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }]
    });
}
```

And markup:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="detail" style="min-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response.Its working..!!! 
If a need different charts on click what changes I have to do? Presently I can see same charts on each bar click.

Comment: Feed second chart with specific data, in my example all of them have the same values: `data: [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: I am newbie for highcharts. Changing Value of data results in different graph. I want different values of data on different Bar click. Changes in data:[] **bold** will again result in same chart.

Comment: It's not issue from Highcharts, it's up to you how do you pass for a second chart. For example, based on it's name: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/150/

Comment: Few more problems I am facing.. I want to add another chart on click on second chart items in the same way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think so you do not need to have 2 different charts if the charts are related to each other ... what you need is [some thing like this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) ... just click on any one bar and see the magic